# Python не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python

Хотел открыть через командную строку папку которая находиться по пути `"D:\Pq5\venv\Scripts"`. Появляется такая ошибка. Не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Если проверить версию Python, то консоль выводит.
Переменные среды пользователя написано такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в системные переменные такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка в cmd:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы пытаетесь запустить папку. Чтоб перейти в папку воспользуйтесь

```
d:
cd D:\Pq5\venv\Scripts
```

Чтоб открыть проводник пишите

```
start D:\Pq5\venv\Scripts
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ подтолкнул меня на ошибку которую я совершал.